# Simple Form collection, but exclude a specific record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Here is the code I use to generate a select list of Companies.

```
<%= f.association :company, :collection => Company.order('name ASC'), :label => "Company: ", :include_blank => false %>
```

Now the table is pre-populated with a special record "id:1, name:none", I want to exclude this record as a selectable option in the select list that's generated.  How can I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.association :company, :collection => Company.where("id != 1").order('name ASC'), :label => "Company: ", :include_blank => false %>
```

Or

```
In the controller

   @companies = Company.where("id != 1").order('name ASC')

In the view

    <%= f.association :company, :collection => @companies, :label => "Company: ", :include_blank => false %>
```

Comment: How would you move this out of the view and into the controller?

Comment: @ardochhigh, I have updated the answer to answer your question.